# Class Names are not colorized in Android Studio Editor 3.4.1

Tags: android-studio

How do I get Android Studio 3.4.1 editor (running on Windows) to colorize class names?

The settings under File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults > identifiers > default show the right colors! I am also able to see Java classes with the right colors in the preview window, however, the editor itself doesn't colorize class names. Re-opening the Java file doesn't work.
Direct overriding of the color (no inherited values) doesn't work as well.

I experimented by changing keywords which works fine.
From what I see no identifier is colorized.

[image: Settings preview showing the right identifier color]
[image: Class names are still not colorized!]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error resolved itself after a complete refresh and rebuild.